# Django personalized url

Tags: python, django, subdomain

I need to use sub-domains (i think) on Django. I have many "room" on my project and i need to build url with name of room.

Example : If i have a room named "microsoft" and my domain is http://toto.fr i want to have a final url like : "http://microsoft.toto.fr" to go in room of microsoft. I can have few room then few differents url.

How its possible to have this ? Django Sub-Domains can do this ?

Thanks you !

Comment: what have you tried, so far?

Comment: Nothing for the moment, i try to understand django-subdomains to know if its good for me

Answer (score 1):

## About subdomains

I don't think there is a **need** in your case for subdomains. You can very well handle the separation of *rooms* this way:

```
http://toto.fr/microsoft/
http://toto.fr/room2/
http://toto.fr/room3/
```

The difficulty will increase (slightly) if you need to generate these urls (e.g users create new *rooms*).

## Using subdomains

### Reroute from Apache, Nginx etc.

**This is the way I would go and recommend you.**

Each service has its way of doing it so you would need to post a specific question related to the service you will use in production.

**--- edit ---**

The idea here is to have your `urls.py` work the way Django is meant to:

```py
# urls.py

from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('microsoft/', views.microsoft),
]
```

So this means on your localhost you will access urls that look like this:

```
https://localhost:8000/microsoft/something
```

This is how it is going to work behind the scenes. But you can setup your http server (Apache for example) to allow your users to use:

```
https://microsoft.example.com/something
```

Here's an example of configuration (**disclaimer** I am very much not an expert in this, this might not be exactly the correct syntax):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName microsoft.example.com
RedirectPermanent / http://example.com/microsoft
</VirtualHost>
```

So when your user types `https://microsoft.example.com/something`, Apache knows it has to call `https://localhost:8000/microsoft/something` internally.

**--- end edit ---**

### Use a django extension

`django-subdomains` does not seem to be active.

**--- edit ---**

Before going with third party code like `django-subdomains` you should always check if it is being maintained. You can see on [their pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/django-subdomains/) that it is not compatible with Django 2 and 3 (and therefore not compatible with python 3). So this should tell you to **not** go with it.

It would mean for you to start with components that are not being actively maintained and have potential security holes.

**--- end edit ---**

I tried very quickly to set it up with Django 3 and could get it to work.

There is the [this fork](https://github.com/abe312/django-subdomains) that claims compatibility with Django 3 but seems pretty inactive also.

Comment: Hello RomainGZ thanks you for your answer ! 

I need to have an url like : "https://microsoft.toto.fr" not like "http://toto.fr/microsoft/" ! This is possible? 

Then you think the solution django-subdomains is not the good solution for resolve my problem if i understand !

Comment: I edited to answer your question about django-subdomains. I am not aware of a way to make subdomains work easily with native Django urlpatterns. My answer is to look at how to use your http server to redirect. I will detail a bit more in my answer as well.

Comment: Your right for django extension, he is not maintained, thanks for this !

For the example, thanks you very much for your help i understand the idea but... If i create 15 room (microsoft, google, android, asus etc...) i need to have 15 redirection in my conf ?! And i need to update my conf everytime i create a new room :(

Comment: You are right, you should not write 15 redirections. Apache (and probably others) have support for regular expressions. You should search on https://serverfault.com or post a question there as I will not be able to help you with this, sorry. A quick search yields this type of question for example: https://serverfault.com/questions/466346/apache-redirect-domain-and-all-subdomains

Comment: Thanks you very much Romain !

Answer (score 1):

You can handle as many rooms as you want with a variable:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('foo/<str:theroom>/bar/', view_room, name="view-room"),
    ...
]
```

If for instance you access

```
http://youraddress/foo/ubuntu/bar/
```

then Django will call your view function

```
def view_room(request, theroom):
```

with `theroom = ubuntu`.

If you prefer defining subdomains like http://ubuntu.youraddress, you will have to define one subdomain per room in the httpd config file, but also, to declare these subdomains in an authoritative DNS. That might be complicated, and is not a good idea IMHO, since subdomains are rather used to specify which app is called.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.

Yes i need to define as subdomains like ubuntu.youradress ! Ok i understand...